# Excel VBA Button Cell address is wrong

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have a tool, where I insert multiple small button in multiple column  automatically (assume Column C1:C90,E1:E90,G1:G90...), based on some selection criteria. I am using the `.Buttons.Add` method of the `Worksheet` class to create the buttons.

I am unable to find correct cell address when I click on a button. E.g. If I click on button in cell C2, It gives C70 cell address, if I Click on E4 it still gives some other cell address. I tried with following code below. Can anyone help me on this?,

```
Sub Mainscoresheet() 
     ' Mainlineup Macro to add button

    Dim b As Object, RowNumber,ColNumber As Integer 
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller) 
    With b.TopLeftCell 
        RowNumber = .Row
        ColNumber = .Col
    End With 
    MsgBox "Row Number " & RowNumber 
    MsgBox "Row Number " & ColNumber
End Sub
```

I added below the button add function.

```
XRow = 7: xCol = 5
        Do Until wks.Cells(XRow, 1) = ""
        DoEvents
            For i = 1 To M_Count
                Set Bt = wks.Range(Cells(XRow, xCol), Cells(XRow, xCol))
                Set btn = wks.Buttons.Add(Bt.Left + 1, Bt.Top + 1, Bt.Width - 2, Bt.Height - 2)
                With btn
                    .OnAction = "BtnCopy"
                    .Caption = ">>"
                    .name = "Note" & Now
                End With
                xCol = xCol + 2
            Next i
        xCol = 5
        XRow = XRow + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: What type of buttons are they ? Active-X Command Button ? User_Form Command Button ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I use "Buttons.Add" function in VBA code

Comment: @ShaiRado I modified the question with Add button functionality as well. My Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to identify the button that was clicked with the following line:

```
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
```

Using `Application.Caller` in this way relies on each `Button` having a unique name. However, when you create the buttons you use this code:

```
With btn
    .OnAction = "BtnCopy"
    .Caption = ">>"
    .name = "Note" & Now
End With
```

But you use the `Now` function to add an 'id' to the `Button`. Using `Now` means that you may create more than one button with the same name because the code will run quick enough that `Now` will not increment within the code. Also, if you run the code a few times e.g. create buttons in 3 columns in 3 different runs then each set of buttons may likely have the same name. This will confuse `Application.Caller` in that it will just return the `Button` that is the 'first match`.

So you should use a counter to create a unique name for each button. See the code example below that does this for sample set of 10 `Button`s:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CallButton()

    Dim btn As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long

    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With btn.TopLeftCell
        lngRow = .Row
        lngCol = .Column
    End With

    MsgBox "Button name " & btn.Name
    MsgBox "Row Number " & lngRow
    MsgBox "Col Number " & lngCol

End Sub

Sub Make10Buttons()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim btn As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For lng = 1 To 10
        Set rng = ws.Cells(lng + 1, 2)
        Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .OnAction = "CallButton"
            .Caption = ">>"
            .Name = "Note" & lng '<--- need a unique ID for each button
        End With
    Next lng

End Sub
```

You can adapt the sample to work with your code by using `XRow` and `xCol` to create an unique suffix to append to each of your buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much Robin Mackenzie! I modified as you suggested and working as I requested.

Comment: @Manish - glad it helped. Feel free to upvote if you feel the answer was useful.